# How to setup tables/rows for flask app in Heroku postgreSQL database

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, heroku-postgres

I am currently trying to set up my database tables/rows for a PostgreSQL/Flask app that I recently deployed to Heroku, but am unsure of how to go about it. Here are my tables in the models.py file:

```
class User (db.Model):
    """User in the system"""
    __tablename__ = "users" 

    id = db.Column( 
        db.Integer, 
        primary_key=True    
    )   
    firstname = db.Column(  
        db.Text,    
        nullable=False  
    )   
    lastname = db.Column(   
        db.Text,    
        nullable=False  
    )   
    username = db.Column(   
        db.Text,    
        nullable=False, 
        unique=True 
    )   
    email = db.Column(  
        db.Text,    
        nullable=False, 
        unique=True 
    )   
    password = db.Column(   
        db.Text,    
        nullable=False  
    )   
    image = db.Column(  
        db.Text 
    )   
    state = db.Column(  
        db.Text,    
        nullable=False  
    )   
    vax_date = db.Column(   
        db.Text 
    )   
    covid_status = db.Column(   
        db.Text
    )
    review = db.relationship('Review', backref='users')

    @classmethod
    def signup(cls, firstname, lastname, username,
            email, password, image, state, vax_date, covid_status):
        """Sign up user. Hashes password and adds user to system."""
        hashed_pwd = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password).decode('UTF-8')

        user = User(
            firstname=firstname,
            lastname=lastname,
            username=username,
            email=email,
            password=hashed_pwd,
            image=image,
            state=state,
            vax_date=vax_date,
            covid_status=covid_status)

        db.session.add(user)
        return user

    @classmethod
    def authenticate(cls, username, password):

        user = cls.query.filter_by(username=username).first()

        if user:
            is_auth = bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, password)
            if is_auth:
                return user

        return False


class Review (db.Model):   
    """Reviews made by users for testing locations"""
    __tablename__ = "reviews" 

    id = db.Column( 
        db.Integer, 
        primary_key=True    
    )   
    location = db.Column(   
        db.Text,    
        nullable=False  
    )   
    description = db.Column(
        db.Text,
        nullable=False
    )   
    user_id = db.Column(    
        db.Integer, 
        db.ForeignKey('users.id', ondelete='CASCADE'),  
        nullable=False  
    )   
    user = db.relationship('User', backref="reviews", passive_deletes=True)
```

Right now when I try to create a user, I am able to create an account, but certain features do not work and I keep losing the user's session. I understand that this stems from the tables/rows not being created. How can I set this information up on my Heroku database?

**UPDATE**
after running `heroku run python manage.py shell` and `db.create_all()` I receive nothing. Here is a photo:

[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yd5Wa.png)

Comment: Have you run `heroku run python manage.py shell`, and then `db.create_all()`?

Comment: I have just tried it and nothing happens. When I run ```db.create_all()``` I don't receive any response. I will attach a photo of what I am seeing

Comment: The command `db.create_all()` is Python code, and needs to be run once you get to a Python prompt. It also needs to be run on Heroku since that's where the PostgreSQL database is located. From the photo, it looks like you ran the command on your local server's command line...